# QGIS Layout: Making a map frame in a certain scale bar style with world coordinates of the map (view) extent

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

Currently I am making some layouts for my some templates we are going to use. We would also like to have a certain border "frame" on to make the coordinate grid clear. The frame is supposed to look like this:

[image: Frame in general]

At first this looks simple we just need to make the frame based on a certain scale bar style, but here things get a bit more complex only that but they also have integrated the X and Y Coordinates of the map (view) extent. Sometimes like this for certain maps:
[image]

But other times like this:
[image]

So how do we do this? Not to mention this has to update dynamicly since we are making "templates" layouts, this has to automaticity update and soon as the view and extent changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my answer in a certain video here: sorry for posting the question here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4q_w9hAknI.

Just add a grid/raster on the map my the layer.